# Write the indicated case of taylor's formula

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have this problem: "Write the indicated case of Taylor's formula for the given function. What is the Lagrange remainder in each case?

$f(x) = \ln{x}$

$a = 1, n = 6$ "

That's the information I got. I know how to find the $P_n(x)$ of $f(x)$ but im not sure what they're asking about here(english is not my first language).. Would anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They want you to express the function as

$$f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^6 {f^{(k)}(1)\over k!}(x - 1)^k + {f^{(7)}(c)\over 7!}(x - 1)^7$$

for some $c$ between $x$ and $1$. That last term is called "the Lagrange form of the remainder" (or just the "Lagrange remainder"). Note that the value of $c$ depends on the value of $x$.